# HyperLink popup with parameter in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, popup

When I click to a HyperLink, I want to open a popup with it. How can I do this?

My **HyperLink** is such as:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hplToplamBegeni" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "../Yazar/PostLikes.aspx?PostID="+ Eval("PostID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create PopUp with <asp:HyperLink> that is passing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778000/create-popup-with-asphyperlink-that-is-passing-parameters)

Comment: Actually, I saw that link. However, when I tried that solution that made a fault like this; "The server tag format is not appropriate." I used the codes like this; <asp:HyperLink ID="hplToplamBegeni" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" onClick='<%# "window.open('../Yazar/PostLikes.aspx" + "?PostID=" + Eval("PostID") + ",'name','height=550, width=790,toolbar=no, directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no'); return false;%>' Target="_blank" ></asp:HyperLink>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hyperlink that uses javascript should work for you.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hplToplamBegeni" Text="popup"
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("../Yazar/PostLikes.aspx?PostID={0}", Eval("PostID"))%>' 
      onclick="javascript:w= window.open(this.href,'PostID',
     'left=20,top=20,width=1500,height=300,toolbar=0,resizable=0');return false;">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

If there are further issues. Check the pathing that the url entered is correct and the PostID is correctly utilized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linkbutton instead and onclientclick to issue a javascript function.

See this link for further detail. 
https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537291/how-to-call-javascript-from-asp-net-hyperlink-control&ved=0ahUKEwjUw7XG48fSAhWDiiwKHbBsC0gQFggcMAE&usg=AFQjCNG0uD1rMI05tUjjk7DVcn78yNZTrQ